# FBX Import resets its position after saving the project file

Tags: modeling, rigging, edit-mode, import, .fbx

After importing and editing a model in .fbx, it keeps on resetting its position. I've had a car body, then "cut out" the door from it (using "separate") and now the new created  door object keeps on resetting its position every time I save and load. I tried copying mesh to another file, tried to maybe clear some object data values, but nothing helps. I need to make a rig with bones for this model, and even when I parent my door to a door bone the mesh will still go flying back to some unspecified location at the grid.[image: the door is separated from the body and I haven't moved it(and don't need to)]

[image: save and load, the doors fly to the grid for no reason(there are two of them because of the mirror modifier)]

So my question is, how do I stop my separated objects from snapping back to some weird location? Is there a way to "unlink" them from the main body mesh? On top of that, my transform fields are colored green for some reason. Why is that?

Comment: I should mention that the original base mesh was created in 3dsmax, if that helps.

Comment: Seems the imported objects are animated (transform value boxes highlighted in *green*). Either try to clear the animations *or* uncheck *Animation* when importing the fbx file.